# Can I separate a project in git?

Tags: git

I've got project that consists of a few small apps. Is it possible to separate them and after some work bring changes back to main?

Comment: What do you mean by separate them?  Do you want to make the projects into submodules or something?

Comment: My main app has some menu that launching each other. I want to build small apps.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to do this would be using [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). They, like most of git, are very flexible and should be able to fit your workflow. While you could contort git's branching to do something similar, submodules are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Each app a separate branch and then once you are finished you could merge them back to master branch when you are done.

Comment: For example I have main project. I need to start new branch "project1", erase all files that doesn't needed by project1 and when I had done with project1 than I will merge branch "project1" to main thread. As I right understand?

Comment: well I would create a project1 folder and then place all the files needed in there, cause if the main project needs the files or has simular name files you could have merge problems

Comment: But I have an android project and all source files of main project must be in src directory.

Comment: not to update on android programming, but can't you have a sub folder inside of the src folder

Answer (score 0):

If you mean splitting them in git repository's. Yes, it's possible. Initalize a new repository for every part and put them in there. After you are done you can use a pull request to merge them together.

But i would try branches so look to Egryan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create and work on topic and long running branches, merge between them and delete them.
Take a look for more details http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging